# Need command to check permgenspace in running tomcat server

Tags: linux, tomcat

I need a command to check the permgenspace in tomcat server. The basic is if I am hitting permgenspace error I want to see the space there.

I used below command to check permgenspace, It is always showing same size eventhough Tomcat may hits the java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space error.

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal tomcat | grep PermSize
uintx AdaptivePermSizeWeight                    = 20              {product}           
uintx MaxPermSize                               = 174063616       {pd product}        
uintx PermSize                                  = 21757952        {pd product}
```

Error: Could not find or load main class tomcat

Please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the following command:

> jstat -gcpermcapacity SERVERPID

For `java 8+` this command is deprecated; Use these ones instead :

> jstat -gcutil SERVERPID 
>   jstat -gc SERVERPID

Source : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html#gcpermcapacity_option

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

> export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx10246m -XX:NewSize=256m
>   -XX:MaxNewSize=356m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=356m"

You can change the actual heap size and PermGen Space as per your requirement.

Restart and run tomcat command again

Comment: Thanks . This command would help after hitting the permGen issue to overcome the problem.

But would like to check the permgenspace , can you please suggest a command which can be used for the permgenspace check (basically I am trying to do a monitoring process)